# Does streaming video by chromecast 2 worth 2-times more bandwidth comparing to direct streaming via SmartTV?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, video, streaming

I have a router with connected SDD disk. The router has enabled DNLA server option, so I can stream video from SSD to any device that support that feature. I have 2 setups with 2 different TV set:

1. TV with Smart TV, that could directly stream data from DNLA server (connect to server via WiFi).
2. Quite old TV with connected Chromecast 2. I use my mobile phone with installed DNLA client. So I use mobile phone to choose content from DNLA server and select as render device - Chromecast 2. Everything connected via WiFi also.

Second solution has a bad performance in case of good quality video.

I have an idea that it is because video in 2nd setup goes 2 times via Wifi: first time from DNLA server to mobile phone, then it is goes from mobile phone to chrome cast. So such stream require 2x more traffic over local network.

It can be that it works other way: mobile phone just do not act as client for downloading video and just pass some kind of "shortcut" to chromecast 2. In this case such setup has no disadvantages in terms of traffic comparing to te 1st setup with Smart TV and the root cause of problem is quite ow performance of chromecast decoding.

So, how actually streaming by chromecast from DNLA server via modile phone works?

Answer (score 0):

This type of troubles usually are due the following reasons.
-ISP is not providing the right bandwidth to supply final user devices needs. 
-final User access point is not right located so Network transmisión is negatively impacted. 
-router is not configured to allow the bandwidth needed And MTU on the internet interface. 
-un authorized users are using the services which impact negatively Network performance.
Additionally video streaming can be affected due not have a prior TCP conexión for UDP usage which means access not secure video streaming, also is recomended to change wifi password to avoid not authorized users reduce internet usage. Video streming is not affected due phone management of services but the Connections to the server itself. The following files can help: 
https://www.pocket-lint.com/tv/news/google/129736-google-chromecast-tips-and-tricks-15-ways-to-enhance-your-streaming-experience